# Sending iMessage that supposably does not get delivered

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

My niece has an iPhone 8 which is acting up. When she sends an iMessage to another user, the message gets sent and received. She however does not see a status (i.e. delivered or read). Instead, after a few minutes she gets a push message stating that the message could not be sent/delivered. The original message then has a red exclamation mark next to it.

As mentioned, the message however was sent and received. This happens when sending messages to any iMessage user no matter if sent over wifi or mobile networks. It even happens, after the recipient has replied.

I have restarted the device, logged out of iCloud and reset the network settings. Nothing seems to fix the issue.

Does anyone have an idea what the cause could be?

Thanks for any tips

PS: She is running iOS 12.3.1 and it wasn't always like this. It started happening a couple of weeks ago. It happens to roughly 95% of the messages she sends. There is no real pattern to the few messages that get sent successfully, often the next message will already throw an error.

Comment: Was it blue or green?